# Javascript fs.readfile() Not Saving to Variable

Tags: javascript, fs

I am trying to use javascrtipt `fs.readfile()`, but I can't get it to store what it has read to a variable. Here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs')

var importantFinalCode = "waiting..."

fs.readFile("\pvMLTest.txt", "utf8", 
function(err, data){
  importantFinalCode = JSON.parse(data)
})


do {
  console.log("...")
} while (importantFinalCode == "waiting...")

console.log(importantFinalCode)
```

For some reason, it just infinitely logs `...`, even though the function says to set the variable `importantFinalCode` to what it is reading. Do I need to make it a global variable? If so, how?

By the way, here is the file it is reading (`pvMLTest.txt`):

```
[["1", "2", "3"], ["3", "2", "4"]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed your issue. This was running an infinite loop due to the scope of the callback function within `fs.readFile`. Once you added your txt file data to the variable within the readFile function, it belonged to that function.

The do / while loop was accessing your gloabally assigned variable, instead of the one within the function.

Moving your loop into the callback function, fixed the issue. But not sure why you would have `let importantFinalCode = "waiting..."` because as soon as the readFile function runs, it changes the value of importantFinalCode.

```
const fs = require('fs')

let importantFinalCode = "waiting..."

fs.readFile("\pvMLTest.txt", "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    importantFinalCode = data

    do {
        console.log("...")
    } while (importantFinalCode === "waiting...");
    console.log(importantFinalCode)
})
```

If you wanted to present the user with `"waiting..."` you could use a for loop like:

```
const fs = require('fs')

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    let importantFinalCode = "waiting..."
    console.log(importantFinalCode)
}

fs.readFile("\pvMLTest.txt", "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    importantFinalCode = data

    console.log(importantFinalCode)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I access the value of ```importantFinalCode``` **outside** of the function?

Comment: @StackUnderflow your use case shouldn't force you to do this and you should never try to do this.

Comment: @GuerricP Ok, I'm new to javascript, so sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but I am trying to figure out how I can read a file in javascript, then set the text of the file to a variable that can be accessed by the rest of the code. The ```do-while``` loop was just an example of using it in code.

Comment: One of JavaScript's main features is that eveything is asynchronous. That means you don't maintain a thread alive when waiting for some I/O operation to complete (like disk, network, ...). Given this, your code should be a chain of callbacks (you could also use `async`/`await` syntax in order to flatten the code). If this JavaScript's feature is not useful for you, you can still use `readFileSync` which returns the content of the file, instead of `readFile` that takes a callback

Answer (score 3):

The following code is an infinite loop that takes up all of the event loop - therefore your script never completes:

```
do {
  console.log("...")
} while (importantFinalCode == "waiting...")
```

You can put the console into `fs.readFile` callback to be executed after file reading complete:

```
const fs = require('fs')

var importantFinalCode = "waiting..."

fs.readFile("pvMLTest.txt", "utf8", 
function(err, data){
  importantFinalCode = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log(importantFinalCode)
})
```

If your file is really big and you want to see the progress of its loading then you can use streams to read it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sourceFile = 'pvMLTest.txt';

var importantFinalCode = "waiting...";
console.log(importantFinalCode);

var data = '';
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);

readStream.on('data', function(buffer) {
    console.log('...');
    data += buffer;
});
readStream.on('end', function() {
    importantFinalCode = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(importantFinalCode);
});
```

Comment: didnt know about streams...this is handy and id imagine what the OP is looking for. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
fs.readFile("\pvMLTest.txt", "utf8", 
function(err, data){
  importantFinalCode = JSON.parse(data)
})
```

You are telling JavaScript to execute the callback function `function(err, data){` later. Later means whens the data arrives, and it also means when the current callstack is empty. By doing this :

```
do {
  console.log("...")
} while (importantFinalCode == "waiting...")
```

You are maintaining the current callstack alive forever. In short, the current callstack waits for the data, but the data callback waits for the current callstack to be empty.
This is a kind of deadlock.

Whatever you want to do with the data, it must go inside the callback.

I suggest you read about the JavaScript's runtime specification which will help you understand why your code doesn't work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop